# Can I get a wireless boiler enable signal?

Tags: boiler, central-heating

I have wireless thermostats which are connected to my wiring centre which controls the pump and valves for the underfloor heating downstairs. On my wiring centre I have a boiler enable signal, which I plan to route up two stories to where my thermal store is located. Routing a wire all this way is quite a task, as the rooms have all been decorated and flooring is down and so on.

As I already have wireless thermostats (to make positioning them easier), I went looking for a wireless boiler enable signal type of device. But I cannot find anything of the sort. Wireless thermostats appear to be the only wireless item when looking at heating. Am I just looking in the wrong place, or would I be better off putting something together myself?

Comment: you would be better off DIY, but it might take some homework. I would have the signal light an LED, then sense that LED with a cheap wifi-connected microcontroller. The other end gets a microcontroller-controlled relay that activates on-demand, allowing remote monitoring, logs, and manual over-ride.

Comment: Where are you on this planet?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I'm in the UK